# How to use the EventStore Embedded Client?

Tags: .net, database, eventstoredb

There seem to be no docs regarding how to set up, run, and connect to an Embedded EventStore client using the EventStore.Client.Embedded nuget package. With the following code:

```
ClusterVNode node = EmbeddedVNodeBuilder
    .AsSingleNode()
    .RunInMemory()
    .OnDefaultEndpoints()
    .Build();

var connection = EmbeddedEventStoreConnection.Create(node);
await connection.ConnectAsync();
var sampleEventData = new EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), "myTestEvent", false, new byte[] { 6, 10, 15 }, null);
WriteResult writeResult = await connection.AppendToStreamAsync("sampleStream, ExpectedVersion.NoStream, sampleEventData);
```

Everything seems to work fine up until the `AppendToStreamAsync` line, which throws the following exception:

> Expected response of EventStore.Core.Messages.ClientMessage+WriteEventsCompleted, received EventStore.Core.Messages.ClientMessage+NotHandled instead.

What part of the magic incantation is missing to get around this exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things are missing here. First, when using the embedded eventstore client, you have to start the node:

```
node.Start();
```

Second, you have to wait for the node to become master before you can use the connection. The `ClusterVNode` has an event named `NodeStatusChanged` that you can listen to and find out when there is a master node. The following should work:

```
ClusterVNode node = EmbeddedVNodeBuilder
    .AsSingleNode()
    .RunInMemory()
    .OnDefaultEndpoints()
    .Build();

bool isNodeMaster = false;
node.NodeStatusChanged += (sender, args) => {
    isNodeMaster = args.NewVNodeState == VNodeState.Master;
};
node.Start();

var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
while (!isNodeMaster) {
    if (stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds > 20) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
        "Waited too long (20 seconds) for EventStore node to become master.");
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1);
}
stopwatch.Stop();

var connection = EmbeddedEventStoreConnection.Create(node);
await connection.ConnectAsync();
var sampleEventData = new EventData(Guid.NewGuid(), "myTestEvent", false, new byte[] { 6, 10, 15 }, null);
WriteResult writeResult = await connection.AppendToStreamAsync("sampleStream, ExpectedVersion.NoStream, sampleEventData);
```

The stopwatch stuff isn't necessary, but is helpful to break out of the `while` loop when something goes wrong and a node never becomes master.

If you put a breakpoint in the event handler delegate, you will notice that the `node` progresses through 3 `VNodeState`s. First it will be `VNodeState.Unknown`, then `VNodeState.PreMaster`, then finally `VNodeState.Master`.

You also shouldn't need to wait for the node to become master before creating the connection and invoking `ConnectAsync()` on it. However, you will need to wait for the node to become master before you can invoke any other methods like `AppendToStreamAsync` on it without running into the exception in your original question.

Comment: If the example is for a cluster shouldn't it be using `AsClusterMember()` instead of `AsSingleNode()`?

Comment: Any idea why I can't browse the stream when starting a node embedded api? I set external http on port 2113 but localhost:2113 doesn't open.

Comment: You can use node.StartAndWaitUntilReady().Wait(); and avoid all the state checking part...
Don't be fooled by the class name, the example is of single nodes, to join a cluster one has to use AsClusterMember(clusterSize).
[Reference](https://eventstore.org/docs/dotnet-api/embedded-client/index.html)